# HDMI Displaying on TV but Not Displaying Correctly. Fixes?

Tags: 12.04, display, hdmi

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. This is the strangest problem ever and I have no idea how to describe it, but I'll try. I got the audio working with the HDMI, and then it shows my Ubuntu desktop on the TV screen but does not show any programs I have open? It sometimes shows my mouse, but only if it's on the sidebar, and only sometimes.. Weird right? Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu by default uses the 'Extend' configuration when connecting to an external monitor, this configuration basically *extends* your screen. I think that if you hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> when the mouse is at the edge, it'll cross over to the other display. You can use this to move a window over to the other display.

You can make it clone the displays by going here

> System Settings -> Displays

and changing the settings as you like.